# strtotime & datediff

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime, datediff

i would like to ask you for some help about my problem.

my current code:

```
require_once 'MysqliDb.php';
$db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'xy', 'xy', 'xy');
$users = $db->rawQuery('select * from police where datediff(skadenca,current_date())=30');
```

So now i select all queries where current date is +30days...but problem is because i want to use that script so send sms for birtdays too, si i need to somehow ignore year in current_date()...so i would like maybe to select full date, but strtotime and delete year, so i would need just day and month...

is there any quick solution for that?

Sorry but i'm still learning about php and sql, so probably my question will sound stupid?

Thanks for all answers

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: i dont know what exactly you are asking me, but i have regular shared hosting, so php, apache, mysql, phpmysqladmin ...

Comment: MySQL is a dbms!

Comment: aha ok, so my dbms is MySQL :) what now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the month and day from the dates (after adding 30 days to the current date), and compare that:

```
where date_format(skadenca, '%m%d') = 
      date_format(date_add(current_date(), interval 30 day), '%m%d')
```

Note however, that if the birthdate is on 29 February, there might not be a match in the current year.

#### On the birthday itself

You could use this comparison:

```
where date_format(skadenca, '%m%d') = date_format(current_date(), '%m%d')
```

To also match a day when the birthday is on 29 February, and the current year is not a leap year, extend to this:

```
where (date_format(skadenca, '%m%d') = date_format(current_date(), '%m%d')
    or date_format(skadenca, '%m%d') = '0229' and dayofyear(current_date()) = 60)
```

This will match 1 March when the birthday is on 29 February and the current year is not a leap year.

In your code it should look like this -- this uses a field `rojstvo` like you mention in comments:

```
$users = $db->rawQuery("
    select * from police 
    where (date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = date_format(current_date(), '%m%d')
        or date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = '0229' and dayofyear(current_date()) = 60)
");
```

Comment: hey,,,...looks like this works...only thing i probably didnt mention...i would like to send sms for birthdays exactly on the same day...so if i have date in sql database 1.3.1988, i would like to send it exactly on the same day not 30 days before

Comment: That will be more problematic for birthdays on the 31st of the month... will only work when birthday is 31 August.

Comment: so there is no way so query out rows with birthdays for example on 15.3 no matter which year?

Comment: Sure there is, for 15.3 it would work. I am just asking what to do with the days of the month that don't exist in the preceding month.

Comment: hmm dont know if i understand you...but my logic is for example if today is 31.1 with query i'll search for all buddies with birthday on 31.1 no matter which year...query them out and proceed to sms sending code...so i dont get it why its important which day is, because i want to send it on the same day when birthday is then proceding date would be the same?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted the same day but the month before. I have updated my answer with a second section for matching the same day and same month.

Comment: hey..i used this code for birthday on 29 february, but i get http error 500 when i use it...

Comment: That seems unrelated. Could you execute this directly in the phpMyAdmin tool without PHP?

Comment: hmmm yeah i see-weird think then...because when i delete this part from code its okay, when i paste it back i get http 500 error...hmmm may be because of my php version or mysql version on server?

Comment: i tried to run on some php online coders..and got this error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: So that explains the 500 error -- make sure you include proper error handing in your PHP code. You must have a mistake in your attempt, which is not there in the fiddle I provided. Check at which position the error is. Normally MySql provides a bit more context ("near ...") in the error message. Which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: maybe this will help: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '') = date_format(current_date(' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) on line number 7

Comment: PHP version: 5.6.33 and Server version: 10.0.31-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Comment: Please provide the complete select statement you are actually trying with.

Comment: $users = $db->rawQuery('select * from police where (date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = date_format(current_date(), '%m%d') or date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = '0229' and dayofyear(current_date()) = 60)';

Comment: You should escape the single quotes in the string literal or else use double quotes for delimiting the string literal.

Comment: hmmm i tried many diferent changes about single and double quotes but cant get it work...can you please help me where is the problem exactly? this is my complete code of file: https://codeshare.io/jGzQ9

Comment: Why did you drop the `select ... from ...` part? Starting SQL with `where` is invalid. Also the outer quotes should be double quotes, otherwise they conflict with the quotes that are part of the query itself (this is quite basic). See addition to my answer.

Comment: i used your code above and now works like a charm :) thank you very much for your patience and help :)  tell me can i donate you somewhere for your time?

Comment: Thank you very very much :)) have a nice day

Comment: maybe one more problem :) i have in database for example 10 records for the same person,...and then he gets 10x sms for birthday..is thar any quick solution to send sms just once?

Comment: look into `select distinct`.

Comment: i already tried with but it doesnt work...:select DISTINCT * from police 
    where (date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = date_format(current_date(), '%m%d')
        or date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = '0229' and dayofyear(current_date()) = 60)

Comment: is this correct:SELECT DISTINCT rojstvo from police 
    where (date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = date_format(current_date(), '%m%d')
        or date_format(rojstvo, '%m%d') = '0229' and dayofyear(current_date()) = 60)

Comment: Not with `*`. You need to select the user ID, or whatever is the person's unique reference (maybe phone number)? As soon as you select one field that is different, `distinct` will produce the two (or more) records.

Comment: looks like we commented in the same time :D got it now how it works after reading a little bit :) thank you again